# OpenGL Frag Shader texture fades after every write

Tags: opengl, shader

I have a program that takes the following texture:

[image]

which is generated via FreeType2. Basically, it's creating a texture atlas for every character that I've requested to be drawn. As you can see, the characters are bright and clear. In fact, you can see that the top-leftmost pixel of the lowercase 'i' has a value of `71` (out of `255`) or `0.7098` when I inspect the texture in RenderDoc.

Next, the engine blits letters onto a Framebuffer Object. This is done via textured quads. The vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec2 inVertexPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec2 inTexelCoords;
layout(location=2) in float inDepth;

out vec2 texelCoords;
out float depth;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(inVertexPosition.x,-inVertexPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    texelCoords = vec2(inTexelCoords.x,1-inTexelCoords.y);
    depth = inDepth;
}
```

And the frag shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) out vec4 frag_colour;

in vec2 texelCoords;
in float depth;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform vec4 uTextColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 c = texture(uTexture,texelCoords);
    frag_colour = uTextColor * c.r;
    gl_FragDepth = depth;
}
```

As you can see, it's sets the pixel color to be a factor of the red channel.

However, when I view the contents of the FBO via RenderDoc, and saved out to file here, you see this:

[image]

If you look at this without transparency (just a second layer added underneath in Gimp to illustrate better):

[image]

You can see that the text is a little faded compared to what it was before. If you look at the top-leftmost pixel of the lowercase 'i', it's now a value of `50.2`, or for a range of 0-1 it's `0.50196` (via RenderDoc).

Next, when the FBO is finally put onto the screen via another textured quad it fades even more. First here's the vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec2 inVertexPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec2 inTexelCoords;

varying vec2 texelCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(inVertexPosition.x,-inVertexPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    texelCoords = vec2(inTexelCoords.x,1-inTexelCoords.y);
}
```

and the fragment shader:

```
#version 330

precision highp float;

layout(location=0) out vec4 frag_colour;

varying vec2 texelCoords;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 c = texture(uTexture,texelCoords);
    frag_colour = c;
}
```

The results, as I said are more faded than before:

original:
[image]

gimp background for clarity:

[image]

now that pixel has a value of `25.1`  or `0.05139`.

**What is causing this fading after every render?**

I think it's important to note that the brighter areas don't fade.

My Framebuffer creation code

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_framebuffer);
glGenTextures(1, &m_fboColorAttachment);
glGenTextures(1, &m_fboAdditionalInfo);
glGenTextures(1, &m_fboDepthStencil);

glCall(glBindFramebuffer,GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);

    /* setup color output 0 */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboColorAttachment);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glCall(glTexImage2D, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, screenDimensionsX, screenDimensionsY, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboColorAttachment, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    /* setup color output 1 */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboAdditionalInfo);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glCall(glTexImage2D, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, screenDimensionsX, screenDimensionsY, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboAdditionalInfo, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    /* setup depth and stencil */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboDepthStencil);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glCall(glTexImage2D, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, screenDimensionsX, screenDimensionsY, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, nullptr);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fboDepthStencil, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The initial (red) texture creation:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1,&textureData.texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureData.texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, 500, 500, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

My blending is done as

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: What would values of `50.2` or `25.1` (out of 255) even _be_ in some integer representation? Apart from that, check your texture filters, check your texcoords, check your uniforms, check your framebuffer formats, check your blend setup. This question is unanswerable because it lacks a description of most of the state which would control the actual output colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> has a value of `71` (out of `255`) or `0.7098`

No idea, what you even mean here. `71/255` would be `0.278`. `0.7098` normalized would be `181` out of `255`.  Looks like your "out of 255" are just percentage values, out of 100%.

> glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

You use that color values from the red channel also as alpha, so, when you have blending enabled, you end up with `0.7098*0.7098=.5038`. Since the result will be rounded to the nearest reprersentable value, we rather end with `181/255 * 181/255 = .50382` rounded to `128/255`

> it's now a value of `50.2`, or for a range of 0-1 it's `0.50196`

`128/255` is `0.50196078...`.

So the solution is: disable blending for all steps when you don't need it. Or if you need it, set useful alpha values.

Side note:

> now that pixel has a value of `25.1` or `0.05139`.

No Idea what this means, the `25.1` does not relate to `0.05139` in any obvious way, you definitively switched the meaning of those values again.

Comment: Load the pngs into Gimp. The integer values are from gimp (even with decimal values... I dont know what gimp is doing). It's definitely out of 255 though. The floats are from renderdoc, the pngs are saved from renderdoc.

Comment: "The integer values are from gimp (even with decimal values...)". No. _integers_ by the very definition don't have decimals. I also don't have an idea what values from GIMP you might mean.

Comment: load the pngs in the latest version of gimp. Use the eyedropper tool to check the colour values. Gimp shows decimal values.